# JAXWS validation : how to

Tags: validation, jax-ws

I'm developing a simple web service using java ee stack.
The business objects are the POJOs annotated with JPA and Bean Validation rules.

The business methods are exposed through the ws. 
The Ws is annotated with:

```
@SchemaValidation()
@WebService()
@Stateless
```

When I'm calling the WS through a simple java-main app with invalid params, I get the exceptions on the server side, in the business objects layer, my WS layer seems does not make the validation.

My goal is to protect as much as possible my business layer from the invalid data in the way to have the verification logic on the WS side.

How can I implement this?

Comment: Did you specify restrictions in your XSD Schemas?

Comment: Yes, the XSD schema has beed generated, but actually not used. Finally, I have switched to Bean Validation JSR.

Comment: Oh, ok. Just for future reference. @SchemaValidation validates only against the restrictions specified in the XSD Schema, so if the generated XSD Schema do not define those, then it won't work. Might have to add them manually.